# What is the name of a technique for finding $K_n$'s in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, computer-science, python, programming

It has something to do with heating the graph and cooling it down. I had searched a bit about it but now that I have time to go deeper into it it just disappeared from my history.
I remember seeing a python code for it with heating and cooling the graph in very specific temperatures

Comment: Finding cliques?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the problem of finding $K_n$'s in a graph is the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

The technique you're describing though (which you self-answered), is something called [simulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

Comment: In this particular case, the person asking the question was clearly thinking of simulated annealing, but forgot the word. Then they remembered that it's simulated annealing, self-answered, but some over-enthusiastic reviewers decided to delete that self-answer...

Comment: I see. Yeah, the question has been pretty heavily edited since I answered. I'll edit